# Excel Conditional Formatting Colour Scales highlight group of cells when another cell is a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, colors

So I have a document that has 2 drop downs with the first acting as a currency selection and the other acting as a discount selection (0% - 50%). Basically whenever I select from the dropdowns the numbers update to whatever the currency is and whatever the discount is.

I want to be able to use conditional formatting so that a colour can correspond to that selection I've made in the discount dropdown - i.e. when I select 5% discount all the cells turn to a green colour, when I select a 50% discount all the cells turn to a red colour and everything else in between updates to the corresponding middle colour range (oranges, yellows etc). I've tried playing around with the formatting using numerical formulas and such but haven't had much luck as the numbers differ depending on the currency etc.

I'm no pro so was just wondering whether there was a formula that basically lets me make a conditional formatting rule if the cell with the dropdown is 5%, 10%, 15% etc

Answer (score 0):

This may not be very eloquent, but it seems like it will work for your requirements.

1. Highlight the Range to be formatted
2. Click the *Conditional Formatting* button, then *Manage Rules*
3. Create the five rules as shown in this image, use the "Formula" option
4. The order of the rules, the values, the comparison operator, and the stop if true flag are all very important to the proper formatting being applied.

Conditional Formatting Manual Color Scale Based on Out of Range Cell:

[image]